# Can I generate Scala bindings for Objective-C and C++ with scala-bindgen?

Tags: scala, binding, scala-native, scala-bindgen

I've recently found scala-bindgen from a Gitter room on Scala Native. Seems like (at the present point in time) they are developing a tool for generating Scala bindings for C header files.

Are there plans for generating Scala bindings for Objective-C and C++ too?

Answer (score 1):

The initial plan consists only on Scala bindings for C language. Bindings for Objective-C is something planned for future. Bindings for C++ are pretty unlikely to happen, due to the complexity involved in such task.

For more information:

http://github.com/frgomes/scala-bindgen